# NodeJS add two hours to date?

Tags: node.js

I've got a date string as such:

`Tue Jul 29 2014 23:44:06 GMT+0000 (UTC)`

How can I add two hours to this?

So I get:

`Tue Jul 29 2014 01:44:06 GMT+0000 (UTC)`

Comment: I would use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: i'm guessing it should be `July 30`?

Comment: @user3490755 check it out.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one solution:

```
var date = new Date('Tue Jul 29 2014 23:44:06 GMT+0000 (UTC)').getTime();
date += (2 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
console.log(new Date(date).toUTCString());
// displays: Wed, 30 Jul 2014 01:44:06 GMT
```

Obviously once you have the (new) date object, you can format the output to your liking if the native Date functions do not give you what you need.

Comment: Note that (at least in my chrome console) `Date(foo)` ignores the value of `foo` and just returns the current Date, whereas `new Date(foo)` returns a date based on the value of `foo`, where `foo` is interpreted as the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch Time (1970.01.01T00.00.00 UTC)

Answer (score 4):

Using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/):

```
var moment = require('moment');

var date1 = moment("Tue Jul 29 2014 23:44:06 GMT+0000 (UTC)");

//sets an internal flag on the moment object.
date1.utc();

console.log(date1.format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ (UTC)"));

//adds 2 hours
date1.add(2, 'h');

console.log(date1.format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ (UTC)"));
```

Prints out the following:

`Tue Jul 29 2014 23:44:06 GMT+0000 (UTC)`

`Wed Jul 30 2014 01:44:06 GMT+0000 (UTC)`

Answer (score 0):

This works well:

```
const epoch = new Date('01-01-2000')
const notBeforeDate = new Date(epoch).setSeconds(notBefore)
const notAfterDate = new Date(epoch).setSeconds(notAfter)
```

NOTE: the `setSeconds()` call actually *adds* seconds to the current Date value, it does not reset the Date to some absolute number of seconds.  This detail is poorly addressed in the documentation and causes a lot of heartache when first trying to work with Dates in JavaScript.